# Package listed under depends does not install when I rebuild a custom R Package

Tags: r, r-library

I'm rebuilding a custom R package which has, among other libraries, RcppArmadillo in the Depends row of the DESCRIPTION file.

I am running R 3.5.1.  When I rebuild the package in RStudio, I get an error:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package 'custom package name'
```

According to the [R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html), packages under Depends/Imports must be installed when the package is rebuilt.

Comment: Is your package source code publicly available, for example in a GitHub repo?

Comment: It is not, unfort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Use `devtools::install()` instead.

## Explanation

According the [RStudio website](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio),

> The Build and Reload command performs several steps in sequence to ensure a clean and correct result:
>       1.Unloads any existing version of the package (including shared libraries ifnecessary).
>       2.Builds and installs the package using R CMD INSTALL.
>       3.Restarts the underlying R session to ensure a clean environment for re-loading the package.
>       4.Reloads the package in the new R session by executing the library function.

While `devtools::install()` will install dependencies for you -- from `help("install.packages")`:

> Uses R CMD INSTALL to install the package. Will **also** try to install
>   dependencies of the package from CRAN, if they're not already
>   installed.

(emphasis added) this is not the case for `R CMD INSTALL` alone (see `?INSTALL` from R or `R CMD INSTALL --help` from the command line, etc. -- there is no mention of installing required dependencies).

So, it appears the language

> In fact, any time your package is installed, those packages will, if
>   not already present, be installed on your computer
>   (devtools::load_all() also checks that the packages are installed).

from Hadley's [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies) is a little specific; it does not pertain to using `R CMD INSTALL` (which RStudio's build function apparently uses), but does work for `devtools::install()`. It's a matter of personal taste, but honestly I highly recommend using [`devtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=devtools) in your package development workflow.

## Example

I removed the package `rbenchmark` from my system via

```
remove.packages("rbenchmark")
```

then created a dummy package by

```
devtools::create("SOexample", rstudio = FALSE)
```

and edited the DESCRIPTION to put `rbenchmark` in Imports, so that `SOexample` depends on it. I added the following code in `R/hello_world.R`:

```
hello_world <- function() print("Hello, world!")
```

I tried `R CMD INSTALL`, but got the error

> *installing to library ‘/home/duckmayr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
>   ERROR: dependency ‘rbenchmark’ is not available for package ‘SOexample’
>   *removing ‘/home/duckmayr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/SOexample’

But, if I try `devtools::install()`:

```
> devtools::install("SOexample/")
Installing SOexample
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rbenchmark_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5093 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 5093 bytes

Installing rbenchmark
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpA0NOMe/devtools723832018149/rbenchmark'  \
  --library='/home/duckmayr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘rbenchmark’ ...
** package ‘rbenchmark’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rbenchmark)
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/home/duckmayr/SOexample'  \
  --library='/home/duckmayr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘SOexample’ ...
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  ‘SOexample’ 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (SOexample)
```

Comment: devtools::install() works - packages not in library are downloaded